# How to show user greeting in liferay web content portlet

Tags: web, liferay, portlet

How to display user greeting (the once which is defined in vm file) in liferay web content portlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which vm file?

Nevertheless you can have in your velocity template for your article

```
#set($us = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalService"))

#set($userId = $getterUtil.getLong($request.get("theme-display").get("user-id")))
$htmlUtil.escape($us.getUserById($userId).getGreeting())
```

for liferay 6+

For previouse versions change first line to

```
#set($us = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil"))
```

For this to work you heve to have

```
journal.template.velocity.restricted.variables=
```

in your portal-ext.properties file. To be more correct serviceLocator must not be stated in

```
journal.template.velocity.restricted.variables=
```

Default for this property is

```
journal.template.velocity.restricted.variables=serviceLocator
```